# convert string to hex and back with different encoding

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

I want to convert a String value to hex and then back to it's ascii value.
when I'm converting it to the hex value i'm doing it with the charset - `cp424`.

this is what i'm trying to do:

```
String str = "abcאבג";               
String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(str.getBytes("cp424")); 
//some action         
String original_value = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray()).toString();
```

My problem is beacuse i'm using `cp424` when converting to hex I need when converting back to get it back to the defult charset.  I tried this convertion in many ways but didn't get the correct value.

how can this be done? how can i get back the original value from the hex value??

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: In the second you call hexString.getBytes("cp424"). Mustn't it be str.getBytes("cp424")?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "to its ASCII value"? What are you *really* trying to achieve? Why bring hex into it at all?

Comment: @Andreas: my mistake, I've changed it to str..

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I need the hex value to check for an unsupported value for my next actions, and i can only check these values by hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `original_value` using the [`String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%2C%20java.lang.String%29) constructor:

```
String original_value = new String(Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray()), "cp424");
```